# solr not showing all indexed doc

Tags: solr, indexing

I have created two cores for creating index for two different purpose. 
The first core is running fine but when I try to created index with second core using DIH, it showed 5 doc created

```
<response>
−
<lst name="responseHeader">
<int name="status">0</int>
<int name="QTime">0</int>
</lst>
−
<lst name="initArgs">
−
<lst name="defaults">
<str name="config">data-config.xml</str>
</lst>
</lst>
<str name="command">full-import</str>
<str name="status">idle</str>
<str name="importResponse"/>
−
<lst name="statusMessages">
<str name="Total Requests made to DataSource">1</str>
<str name="Total Rows Fetched">5</str>
<str name="Total Documents Skipped">0</str>
<str name="Full Dump Started">2011-12-26 12:24:45</str>
−
<str name="">
Indexing completed. Added/Updated: 5 documents. Deleted 0 documents.
</str>
<str name="Committed">2011-12-26 12:24:45</str>
<str name="Optimized">2011-12-26 12:24:45</str>
<str name="Total Documents Processed">5</str>
<str name="Time taken ">0:0:0.52</str>
</lst>
−
<str name="WARNING">
This response format is experimental.  It is likely to change in the future.
</str>
</response>
```

But when I try to display all results with the given below url

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/core1/select/?q=*:*&version=2.2&start=0&rows=10&indent=on
```

but it is showing 1 result only.

Any help will be appreciated...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably are using multivalue=false for the field in question. If you want all 5 documents to be created you have to change this in the schema.

Comment: No, I don't think I need multivalued. I have 5 rows that my query is fetching. And 5 documents are being created as well. But when I search solr with the above given url, it returns only one value...

Comment: They are processed, not created. You probably have same ID for all the documents. So you will only see the last one created.

Comment: Thanks... you are right. I was using the id that was being repeated.